# Hiding tkinter widgets vs destroying and recreating them

Tags: python, tkinter

Hiding tkinter widgets and then putting them back on the grid vs destroying and recreating them. Which is better for a smooth running tkinter app like when you have many widgets to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the case of frame or any other widget:

Hiding is preferred rather than destroying most of the time cause to create a frame again and again will consume more RAM rather than updating/raising the old frame.

Most of the time updating a frame rather than creating it again and again is better.Also if you don't destroy the old frames then ultimately they will tack one above the other and will cause lag after some time.

Comment: I don't think your explanation of RAM is correct. If you destroy a widget, the memory it was using will get reused the next time your program needs more memory. I don't think stacking frames which were hidden will cause any lag.

Comment: Yeah stacking frames doesn't cause lag and is always preferred rather than ceating new one